# how to make jpg downdable in wordpress?

Tags: php

is it possible to make phtos downdable in wordpress? for example here is a path of jpg http://buhehe.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Reisepass-beantragen.jpg
when onclick it shows jpg in browser but don't download it. Is it possible to download jpg onclicking them?
For example: it downloads jpg s here: https://www.hdwallpapers.in/download/2018_mso_mclaren_720s_4k_8k-1280x800.jpg
https://www.hdwallpapers.in/2018_mso_mclaren_720s_4k_8k-wallpapers.html

Answer (score 1):

By default a user can save any image by right clicking on it in their browser and selecting "Save Image..." or similar.

HTML5 offers a `download` attribute to the `<a>` element that will attempt to force the browser to download the image. So your resulting HTML would look like this:

```
<a href="{{ url of image }}" download>
   <img src="{{ url of image }}" alt="Alternate Description for Assistive Technologies" width="700" height="320">
</a>
```

Additionally, the `download` attribute can take a file name too so `download` becomes `download="SaveFileName.jpg"`

Without knowing more about how you want to do this, I cannot offer up any WordPress code.

Comment: Thanks, how can i use it for pdf?

Comment: What do you mean? How to force a PDF file to download? The `download` attribute should work for that too.

Answer (score 1):

The example pictures are delivered with a `Content-Type: application/force-download` header. Others use `application/octet-stream`. You can do the same in your site but you'd need to do this at the server level (Apache config, nginx config, .htaccess config) and not at the application level (WordPress).

This has already been answered in many threads on Stack Overflow, for example [Forcing a download using  in htaccess at WWW root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388994/forcing-a-download-using-filesmatch-in-htaccess-at-www-root).